# Add margin between table and text underneath, MS Office Word 2007

Tags: ms-word, styles, ms-office

I am having a difficult time adding space between a table and paragraphs underneath.

I am trying to create a table style that has some bottom margin or spacing but it doesn't seem to work... note that I am not referring to cell spacing.

For individual tables, I had some success by changing Table Properties-->Text wrapping to around, and setting the positioning to top 3pt, bottom 3pt, and some large number for left and right.

Though text wrapping is greyed out when I am creating a table style.

Any ideas?

Tim

Answer (score 0):

Will it be ok for you if the paragraph style is having a top margin/spacing?
If yes, please try duplicating a style and modify it , From the Format> select the option "paragraph" and add top spacing as desired.Shall give the step if unable to find.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The problem with that is, when i am trying to put a heading under the table, the total spacing will be different from when I try to put a heading under a normal paragraph.